multiple dropdown conflict php mysql
i have 3 dropdown filled automatically from database. type achat /categorie/article.   in type achat there are 2 options: materiel/service. when i select materiel it displays list of categories of materiel idem for service. when i select one categorie from materiel it list all articles inside it correctly but when i select categorie element from service it displays articles from materiel. i dont where is the error. here are my three files:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nouvelle Demande d'Achat</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Nouvelle Demande d'Achat</h2>

    <form id="achatForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="typeAchat">Type d'Achat :</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="typeAchat">
                <option value="">Sélectionner un type d'achat</option>
                <?php
                // Connexion à la base de données 'dac'
                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "casablanca", "casablanca", "dac");

                // Vérifier la connexion
                if (!$conn) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }

                // Requête pour obtenir les types d'achat
                $queryTypeAchat = "SELECT * FROM type_achat";
                $resultTypeAchat = mysqli_query($conn, $queryTypeAchat);

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTypeAchat)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['id_type_achat'] . '">' . $row['nom_type_achat'] . '</option>';
                }

                // Fermer la connexion
                mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="categoriesGroup" style="display: none;">
            <label for="categorieSelect">Catégorie :</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="categorieSelect"></select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="articlesGroup" style="display: none;">
            <label for="articleSelect">Article ou Service :</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="articleSelect"></select>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Soumettre">
    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('typeAchat').addEventListener('change', function() {
            var typeAchat = this.value;
            if (typeAchat !== '') {
                document.getElementById('categoriesGroup').style.display = 'block';

                // Requête AJAX pour charger les catégories correspondantes
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', 'load_categories.php', true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        document.getElementById('categorieSelect').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        document.getElementById('articlesGroup').style.display = 'none';
                    } else {
                        console.error('Request failed. Status: ' + xhr.status);
                    }
                };
                xhr.send('typeAchat=' + typeAchat);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('categoriesGroup').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('articlesGroup').style.display = 'none';
            }
        });

        document.getElementById('categorieSelect').addEventListener('change', function() {
            var categorieId = this.value;
            if (categorieId !== '') {
                // Requête AJAX pour charger les articles correspondants
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', 'load_articles.php', true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        document.getElementById('articleSelect').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        document.getElementById('articlesGroup').style.display = 'block';
                    } else {
                        console.error('Request failed. Status: ' + xhr.status);
                    }
                };
                xhr.send('categorieId=' + categorieId);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('articlesGroup').style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>


load_categories.php
<?php
// Connexion à la base de données 'dac'
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "casablanca", "casablanca", "dac");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['typeAchat'])) {
    $typeAchat = $_POST['typeAchat'];
    
    // Requête pour récupérer les catégories en fonction du type d'achat (materiel ou service)
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categorie_materiels WHERE id_type_achat = $typeAchat";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $options = '<option value="">Sélectionner une catégorie</option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $options .= '<option value="' . $row['id_categorie_materiels'] . '">' . $row['nom_categorie_materiels'] . '</option>';
    }

    // Ajouter les catégories de service en fonction du type d'achat
    $queryService = "SELECT * FROM categorie_services WHERE id_type_achat = $typeAchat";
    $resultService = mysqli_query($conn, $queryService);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultService)) {
        $options .= '<option value="' . $row['id_categorie_services'] . '">' . $row['nom_categorie_services'] . '</option>';
    }

    echo $options;
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>


load_articles.php
<?php
// Connexion à la base de données 'dac'
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "casablanca", "casablanca", "dac");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['categorieId'])) {
    $categorieId = $_POST['categorieId'];

    // Vérifier si la catégorie est associée à du matériel
    $queryMaterial = "SELECT * FROM categorie_materiels WHERE id_categorie_materiels = $categorieId";
    $resultMaterial = mysqli_query($conn, $queryMaterial);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultMaterial) > 0) {
        // Requête pour récupérer les articles de la catégorie de matériel
        $query = "SELECT * FROM materiel WHERE id_categorie_materiel = $categorieId";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        $options = '<option value="">Sélectionner un article</option>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $options .= '<option value="' . $row['id_materiel'] . '">' . $row['nom_materiel'] . '</option>';
        }
    } else {
        // Requête pour récupérer les services de la catégorie
        $queryService = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE id_categorie_services = $categorieId";
        $resultService = mysqli_query($conn, $queryService);

        $options = '<option value="">Sélectionner un service</option>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultService)) {
            $options .= '<option value="' . $row['id_service'] . '">' . $row['nom_service'] . '</option>';
        }
    }

    echo $options;
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>



Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attack. Even if you are escaping variables, its not safe! You should always use prepared statements and parameterized queries in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

In the typeAchat dropdown, some of the options use id_materiel as the value, others use id_service. But nothing prevents rows in each table having the same ID. So when you send the ID to load_articles, there's no way for it to know which table it comes from. You need to add something to the value to specify which table it came from. You can put that as a prefix in the value.
load_categories.php
<?php
// Connexion à la base de données 'dac'
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "casablanca", "casablanca", "dac");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['typeAchat'])) {
    $typeAchat = $_POST['typeAchat'];
    
    // Requête pour récupérer les catégories en fonction du type d'achat (materiel ou service)
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categorie_materiels WHERE id_type_achat = $typeAchat";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $options = '<option value="">Sélectionner une catégorie</option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $options .= '<option value="materiel-' . $row['id_categorie_materiels'] . '">' . $row['nom_categorie_materiels'] . '</option>';
    }

    // Ajouter les catégories de service en fonction du type d'achat
    $queryService = "SELECT * FROM categorie_services WHERE id_type_achat = $typeAchat";
    $resultService = mysqli_query($conn, $queryService);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultService)) {
        $options .= '<option value="service-' . $row['id_categorie_services'] . '">' . $row['nom_categorie_services'] . '</option>';
    }

    echo $options;
}

mysqli_close($conn);

Then extract that from the value in load_articles.php
if (isset($_POST['categorieId'])) {
    [$typeAchat, $categorieId] = explode('-', $_POST['categorieId']);

    if ($typeAchat == 'materiel') {
        // Requête pour récupérer les articles de la catégorie de matériel
        $query = "SELECT * FROM materiel WHERE id_categorie_materiel = $categorieId";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        $options = '<option value="">Sélectionner un article</option>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $options .= '<option value="' . $row['id_materiel'] . '">' . $row['nom_materiel'] . '</option>';
        }
    } elseif ($typeAchat == 'service') {
        // Requête pour récupérer les services de la catégorie
        $queryService = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE id_categorie_services = $categorieId";
        $resultService = mysqli_query($conn, $queryService);

        $options = '<option value="">Sélectionner un service</option>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultService)) {
            $options .= '<option value="' . $row['id_service'] . '">' . $row['nom_service'] . '</option>';
        }
    } else {
        $options = '<option value="">Nothing to select</option>';
    }

    echo $options;
}

mysqli_close($conn);


that uis still insecure. you should rewrite it
